# How do you store the markdown using WMD in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, markdown, wmd

I have implemented the WMD control that Stack Overflow uses into a project of mine, it **almost** works like a charm, but when I save the changes to the database it is saving the HTML version and not the Markdown version.

So where I have this in my text box:

```
**boldtext**
```

It is really saving this:

```
<b>boldtext</b>
```

How do I make it save the Markdown version?

Comment: How are you display the text in preview and in the textarea once it has been saved to the database? Can you share code sample?

Comment: I actually save both versions to the database, both the mark down and html version.  I use Markdown.Net to do the encoding on the server side.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Before you include `wmd.js`, or whatever you've named the WMD editor JavaScript code locally, add one line of JavaScript code:

```
wmd_options = {"output": "Markdown"};
```

This will force the output of the editor to Markdown.

Comment: using this, can you have it output both the markdown AND the html?

Comment: @Ryan: It will simply not autoconvert to html on postback.

Comment: where 's line that I put `wmd_options = {"output" : "Markdown"};`  into?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the new WMD from http://code.google.com/p/wmd-new/, open **wmd.js** and add this line:

```
wmd.wmd_env.output = 'markdown';
```

Excerpt:

```
...
wmd.ieCachedRange = null; // cached textarea selection
wmd.ieRetardedClick = false; // flag

wmd.wmd_env.output = 'markdown'; // force markdown output

// Returns true if the DOM element is visible, false if it's hidden.
// Checks if display is anything other than none.
util.isVisible = function (elem) {
...
```

That should do the trick.